# What is good way to create regional content on BluePrint structure?

Tags: blueprint

I'm designing BluePrint structure, then I'd like to ask how to manage "regional content".
("Reginal content" means content which is commonly used in specific region like Europe, or Asia, etc.)
I think there are following possible way.

1. Create folders for each region in content parent publication(which is used to create content commonly used whole countries in).
   Then create components, for example "Asian news" components in "Asian content" folder.
   And set folder permission to prevent using wrong content(Asian editor uses European content or something like that).
2. Create publications as child of content parent publication, then create regional content in each publications.

I think both of those ways are not much different. Which is best practice of Tridion?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is *either* could be appropriate.

The true answer will be a factor of a number of more considerations - to name but a few....

- What's the frequency of change
- What's the likelihood of the content being used directly (without localization)
- Will only a small part of content be localized (perhaps this can be abstracted out to be the global/regional aspect)
- Who will be managing the content
- Is translation involved (Manual, export, TMS + World Server)
- How could this affect any workflow to be considered
- How many publications are you considering now / in 5 years

Each answer will open up another avenue of exploration - and should be done so as you're considering a Blueprint for a specific client with their current and future projections and expectations.

Answer (score 1):

As a general guideline, I opt for sharing where possible (option 1), especially when the content is authored in a single language, by a centralized group.

This makes a few of Dylan's points easier, especially:

- Translation
- Authorization
- Re-use, sharing

However, the final BluePrint design must match the business needs. Run a workshop and/or present the trade-offs to the business to confirm the best fit. Regional content in regional Publication is okay if sharing isn't a concern.

In the end, keep it practical. Either option doesn't have to be that big of an impact for small sets of content and/or when your developers are familiar with the Core Service.